# cannot ping link-local address from other subnet when defaut gateway route is seted

Tags: networking, linux, debian

i have a problem with my route table i dont know why it doesnt work.

I have two test cases, i did draw a network map for each case.

**currently i cant resolv the goal**.

[testcase-1 network map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LePdC.png)

[testcase-2 network map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwy95.png)

> The goal:

1. laptop-1 can ping raspberry pi **over zeroconf ip**
2. laptop-2 can ping raspberry pi **over zeroconf ip**
3. raspberry pi can ping 8.8.8.8 **over the default route**

> testcase-1

**the default gateway on raspberry pi's eth0 is 192.168.15.180**

- Laptop-1 can ping raspi **over zeroconf ip**
- Laptop-2 **cannot** ping raspi **over zeroconf ip**
- raspi can ping 8.8.8.8 **over the default route**

  Routing table

  ```
  default via 192.168.15.180 dev eth0
  default dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.218.78
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  192.168.15.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.15.6
  ```

> testcase-2

**no default gateway on raspberry pi's eth0**

- Laptop-1 can ping raspi **over zeroconf ip**
- Laptop-2 can ping raspi **over zeroconf ip**
- raspi **cant** ping 8.8.8.8 **over the default route**

  Routing table

  ```
  default dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.218.78
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  192.168.15.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.15.6
  ```

I hope anybody can help me.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

BY definition you cannot ping (or anything else) to a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). It will ONLY work on a link, as the addresses are not routable.

Comment: Link local is layer 2 please read the Post befor you answer i Ping  the linc local Adresses over thr layer 2 switch